# Url not loading in UIWebview, # converting to %23

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Stucked on load the below Local path url in **UIWebview**. Find the url in spinepath, then i converted to url [SpinePathUrl].

My issue is, when i try to load,i'm getting nil value. 
For checking purpose, i pasted the SpinepathUrl into browser it show webpage not found.Then, i changed SpinePathUrl **"arugoswami-4.xhtml%23toc_marker-4"** into **"arugoswami-4.xhtml#toc_marker-4"**, its showed result.

Is the # is my issue in url.? Why the # converted to %23, when it converting from String to Url.

```
spinepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",documentsDirectory,Path];
spinepath = [spinepath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
spinepath = [spinepath stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**[/Users/blazedream/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/E19D2CD0-E0DC-460E-8BC9-97A9C8010910/Documents/UnzippedEpub/OEBPS/*arugoswami-4.xhtml#toc_marker-4*]**

```
NSURL *SpinePathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:spinepath];
```

**[file:///Users/blazedream/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/E19D2CD0-E0DC-460E-8BC9-97A9C8010910/Documents/UnzippedEpub/OEBPS/*arugoswami-4.xhtml%23toc_marker-4*]**

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:SpinePathUrl];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Please clear your question

Comment: you didnot understand?/

Comment: No mate, can u please mark the question and the problem?

Comment: # getting convert to %23, do you know why??

Comment: yes. The # char isn't legal in a valid url. You should encode that to %23

Comment: used NSUTF8 encoding, you can see in above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64302/discussion-between-ramdy-and-gran33).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding fragment manually

```
NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"... arugoswami-4.xhtml"];
NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"#toc_marker-4" relativeToURL:baseUrl];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fullURL];

[myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```